# Get Size of UIElement in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, size, center, uielement

I have a canvas. When I click it, I get the coordinates of the mouse and up (adds a child) has custum control (a thumb with a simply circle) there.
On the screen, logically, the upper left corner is taken as reference when adding. I will wish to place the center of thumb exactly where I click (see picture. Red star = Where I click).

[image]

To do what, I need to get the actual width and height of the thumb, And Then calculate the exact coordonate to place the center of the thumb where the user clicked. Is there a better way ?
In WPF, I used this code, but it doen't work in WinRT.

```
 //Circle in thumb
 Ellipse Bdr = this.GetTemplateChild("Forme") as Ellipse;
 DependencyObject dobj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(Bdr);
 Vector ParentPosition = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset((Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dobj));
 Vector BdrPosition = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset((Visual)dobj);
 return new Point((Position.X+BdrPosition.X) + Bdr.ActualWidth /2,(Position.Y+ ParentPosition.Y) + Bdr.ActualHeight / 2);
```

Can you help me ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` properties remain 0 until the `FrameworkElement` isn't loaded. On other hand, if you've sized `Ellipse` in `ControlTemplate`, you can get it's size on `OnApplyTemplate()`. You can use delegate to pass height and width to container `Page`. i.e.

**ThumbControl**

```
public class ThumbControl : Control
{
    public IThumbSize thumbSize;
    public ThumbControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ThumbControl);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        Ellipse child = this.GetTemplateChild("circle") as Ellipse;
        if (thumbSize != null)
            thumbSize.SizeMeasured(child.Width, child.Height);
    }
}
```

**ThumbControl's Style**

```
 <Style TargetType="local:ThumbControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ThumbControl">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle"
                             Fill="Blue"
                             Height="50"
                             Width="50"></Ellipse>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
  </Style>
```

**IThumb interface**

```
public interface IThumbSize
{
    void SizeMeasured(double width, double height);
}
```

**ContainerPage.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Canvas x:Name="rootCanvas"
            Background="Transparent"
            PointerReleased="rootCanvas_PointerReleased"></Canvas>
</Grid>
```

**ContainerPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class ContainerPage: Page, IThumbSize
{
    ThumbControl thumbControl = new ThumbControl();
    Point touchPoint = new Point();
    public ContainerPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        thumbControl.thumbSize = this;
    }

    private void rootCanvas_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(rootCanvas);
        touchPoint.X = pt.Position.X;
        touchPoint.Y = pt.Position.Y;
        if (!rootCanvas.Children.Contains(thumbControl))
            rootCanvas.Children.Add(thumbControl);
        Canvas.SetLeft(thumbControl, touchPoint.X - (thumbControl.ActualWidth / 2));
        Canvas.SetTop(thumbControl, touchPoint.Y - (thumbControl.ActualHeight / 2));
    }

    public void SizeMeasured(double width, double height)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(thumbControl, touchPoint.X - (width / 2));
        Canvas.SetTop(thumbControl, touchPoint.Y - (height / 2));
    }
}
```

Hope it helped.